# How to render a list items adjacent to each card for nested loop in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested

How to render a list items adjacent to each card for nested loop in reactjs

With the below script I can render the elements successfully. But li tag is not ending with /li tag for each looping element.
Requirement: li tag should end for each element in a loop.
Issue:  li tag is ending at last looping element.

Can you please help where I am missing the logic.

```js
return (
<>
<ul mediaSm={200} mediaMd={936}style={{ paddingBottom: "20px" }}>
     {loading && detail.length
                  ? detail.map(({ firstName, detailList }, i) => (
                     <li key={i}  span={12} spanSm={12}
                        spanMd={6}  spanLg={6}>
                    
                          {detailList.length &&
                             detailList.map((data, j) => ( 
                                <DetailCard
                                   key={j}
                                   member={firstName}
                                   id={data.id}
                                   login={data.loginDate}
                                   logout={data.logoutDate}
                                   status={data.status}
                                   }
                                /> 
                             ))} 
                       </li>
                    ))
                  : null} 
            </ul>
</>
)
```

```html
JSON

0:
detailList: Array(3)
0: {id: "191493389301", loginDate: "5/24/2019", logOutDate: "5/28/2019", status: "closed", …}
1: {id: "191493389300", loginDate: "5/24/2019", logOutDate: "5/28/2019", status: "open",…}
2: {id: "191493389302", loginDate: "5/24/2019", logOutDate: "5/28/2019", status: "inprocess", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
firstName: "Sam"

2:
detailList: Array(1)
0: {id: "191493389401", loginDate: "5/24/2019", logOutDate: "5/28/2019", status: "closed", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
firstName: "Mary"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you should change the misplaced list tag `li`, and also I observed some syntax errors which I fixed. Check out the below return statement code

```
 return (
    <>
        <ul mediaSm={200} mediaMd={936} style={{ paddingBottom: "20px" }}>
            {
                loading && detail.length
                    ? detail.map(({ firstName, detailList }, i) => (
                        detailList.length &&
                        detailList.map((data, j) => (
                            <li key={i} span={12} spanSm={12} spanMd={6} spanLg={6}>
                                <DetailCard
                                    key={j}
                                    member={firstName}
                                    id={data.id}
                                    login={data.loginDate}
                                    logout={data.logoutDate}
                                    status={data.status}
                                />
                            </li>
                        ))
                    ))
                    : null
            }
        </ul>
    </>
 )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for correcting the syntax and solution

Answer (score 1):

From the way you describe your issue, I think the problem you are experiencing is that you expect there to be one `li` tag per `DetailCard` component, but you have wrapped the whole loop that produces `DetailCards` in one `li` element. To fix this problem you should instead move your `li` as the outermost wrapper inside of your `DetailCard` component.